# discord.js / ytdl-core play command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

this is my second question today. I'm using discord.js v13. Earlier I looked into finding out how to make audio play from the bot, and now I am attempting to make a queue work for my discord.js bot. My problem is getting the queue defined from index.js correctly. I will provide the error log along with my code.

error logs: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb8hL.jpg

index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Collection, Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const Levels = require('discord-xp');
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Client({
    presence: {
        status: 'idle',
        afk: false,
        activities: [{
            name: 'The Official Xontavs',
            type: 'WATCHING'
        }],
    },
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS]
});

client.queue = new Map();



const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose.js');

Levels.setURL(`mongodb+srv://discordbot:${process.env.PASS}@bot.z8ki0.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`);
['aliases', 'commands'].forEach(x => client[x] = new Collection());
['command', 'event'].forEach(x => require(`./handlers/${x}`)(client));

mongoose.init();
client.login(process.env.CLIENT_TOKEN); // SECRET TOKEN
```

play.js

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
const { getVoiceConnection, joinVoiceChannel, AudioPlayerStatus, createAudioResource, getNextResource, createAudioPlayer, NoSubscriberBehavior } = require('@discordjs/voice');
const { createReadStream} = require('fs');

module.exports = {
    name: "play",
    category: "music",
    description: "plays a song",
    usage: "<id | mention>",
    run: async (client, message, args, queue) => {
        
        const voiceChannel =  message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You are not in a voice channel.');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT', 'SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You do not have the correct permissions');
        if(!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument');
    
        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
        
        let song = {};
        
        if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
            const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
            song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
        } else {
            const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
                return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
            }
            
            const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
            if (video){
                song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
            } else {
                message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
            }
        }
        
        if (!server_queue){
            
            const queue_constructor = {
                voice_channel: voiceChannel,
                text_channel: message.channel,
                connection: null,
                songs: []
            }
            
            queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
            queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
            
            try {
                const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                    channelId: voiceChannel.id,
                    guildId: message.guild.id,
                    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
                });
                queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
            } catch (err) {
                queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                message.channel.send('Error connecting');
                throw err;
            }
        } else {
            server_queue.songs.push(song);
            return message.channel.send(`**${song.title}** added to queue.`);
        }
        
        
        //audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1}))
        //audioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
                //audioPlayer.stop();
                //connection.destroy();
                //message.channel.send('Leaving VC');
            //});
    }
}

const video_player = async (guild, song, queue) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);
    
    if(!song) {
        connection.destroy();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    
    const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
    song_queue.connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
    
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    audioPlayer.play(createAudioResource(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1}))
    audioPlayer.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    song_queue.text_channel.send(`Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}
```

messageCreate.js (if needed)

```
const del = require('../../functions.js');
const Levels = require('discord-xp');
require('dotenv').config();
const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
const queue = new Map();

module.exports = async (Discord, client, message) => {
    
    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;
    
    const randomXP = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14) + 1; //1-15
    const hasLeveledUP = await Levels.appendXp(message.author.id, message.guild.id, randomXP);
    if (hasLeveledUP) {
        const user = await Levels.fetch(message.author.id, message.guild.id);
        message.channel.send(`${message.member} is now level ${user.level}.`);
    }
    
    //const args = message.content.startsWith(prefix) ? message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g) : message.content.replace(/[^\s]*/, '').trim().split(/ +/g);
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if (cmd.length === 0) return;
    
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(c => c.aliases?.includes(cmd));
    
    if (command) {
        command.run(client, message, args, queue);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated because I'm really not smart and I'm still trying to learn how all this stuff works, especially with discord.js v13

Comment: In `video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);` you put the queue as a second argument and the song as the third when it's supposed to be the other way around ? try replacing it with `video.player(message.guild,songs[0],queue_constructor)`

Comment: that wasn't the fix, but i did realize that i forgot to add the queue to video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]); . adding queue (and a few other things) to the end fixed the problem. video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0], queue, audioPlayer);

Comment: Alright I posted the answer, just approove it so ppl who have the same problem will find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```js
  video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
```

You only put two parameters and as you said in the comments, you only had to change it to this to fix your problem

```js
  video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0], queue, audioPlayer)
```